# What is the reason of the Telugu character crash in iOS, Facebook, and Twitter

Tags: android, ios, unicode

Probably most of us are aware that the case of a Telugu character crashing iOS hit the headlines recently. [Here is the description of the issue.](http://www.newsweek.com/text-bomb-will-crash-your-iphone-seconds-heres-how-fix-it-812214) Apple later released iOS 11.2.6 [to fix the bug](https://www.macrumors.com/2018/02/19/apple-releases-ios-11-2-6/). Moreover, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HRjFSLYTxU) demonstrates that Facebook and Twitter are having trouble rendering the character, too, but they don't crash like iOS.

Regarding the reason of this, the first thing that came to my mind was the Unicode of that character somehow messing things up. But **how exactly**, that is my question. I found [this brief opinion](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/7y2br7/discussion_the_reason_the_telugu_character/) which relates the problem to the concept of a [zero-width non-joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner), but that is not clear. A ZWNJ in and of itself doesn't crash iOS, then what is so special about the ZWNJ contained in that Telugu character? Also, why does it affect iOS, but not Android? Further, how can it cause a system/app to crash; shouldn't the app just display an error and keep functioning?

What is the exact mechanism of this?

Comment: It doesn't effect android because the implementation of font rendering, display, and lookup are different.  ANy bug like this is usually very implementation specific.

Comment: Yes, I know, what I am wondering is what could be that implementation detail that made a character to cause this much trouble. Also folks, what is the reason of the down vote?..

Comment: An easy one would be that they didn't have some table set up at that code point, so by dereferencing it they jumped to uninitialized memory.  It could be anything, without the code of the OS we can't know.